# SAP UI5 Label to display ++ as SuperScript

Tags: label, sapui5, superscript

Need to display ++ as superscript for a label in SAP UI5.
My initial approach was to extend the standard label control and have the property text as `sap.ui.core.HTML()` type, but couldn't go forward.
Need suggestions and of possible code example to do so.

```
sap.m.Label.extend("mylabel.Label", {  
    // the control API:
    library : "sap.m",
    metadata: {
        aggregations: {
        superScript: 'sap.ui.core.HTML'
    },
    properties: {
        text: {
            type: "sap.ui.core.HTML"
        }
    }
},
renderer: function(oRM, oControl) { // static function
    sap.m.LabelRenderer.render(oRM, oControl);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add the content in the **init** method and then render that with the Label class renderer as below

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/m/Label",
               "sap/ui/core/HTML"], function (Label, HTML) {
    "use strict";
    return Label.extend("SuperLabel", {
        metadata : {
            aggregations : {
                 superScript : {
                     type : "sap.ui.core.HTML", multiple : false
                 }
            }
        },
        init : function () {
            this.setAggregation('superScript',new HTML({
                content : "<sup>++</sup>"
           }));
        }
    });
});
```

And I am writing the renderer in other class with name renderer i.e, **SuperLabelRenderer**

```
sap.ui.define([], function () {
    "use strict";
    var SuperLabelRenderer = {};
    SuperLabelRenderer.render = function (oRM, oControl) {
         oRM.write("<div");
         sap.m.LabelRenderer.render(oRM, oControl);
         oRM.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("superScript"));
         oRM.write("</div>");
    };
    return SuperLabelRenderer;
},true);
```